# How to use the value of a string that is yet to be set by scanner/system.in - Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a calculator. It may not be the most efficient way but I would like help on what I have done so far.

```
    package me.Nelsin.Calculator;


    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.util.Scanner;


public class Calculator {


public static void main(String args[]) {

    double answer;
    //2 numbers
    System.out.println("Enter your first number: ");
    Scanner fnumb = new Scanner(System.in);
    double fnum = fnumb.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter your operation, *, /, +, -: ");
    Scanner operation = new Scanner(System.in);
    String op = operation.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your second number: ");
    Scanner snumb = new Scanner(System.in);
    double snum = snumb.nextDouble();

    //Answers
    if(op.equals("*")) {
        answer = fnum * snum;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.println(df.format(answer));
    }   
    if (op.equals("/")) {
        answer = fnum / snum;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.println(df.format(answer));
    }
    if (op.equals("+")) {
        answer = fnum + snum;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.println(df.format(answer));
    } 
    if (op.equals("-")) {
        answer = fnum - snum;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.println(df.format(answer));  
        }
    System.out.println("Enter your operation, *, /, +, -: ");
    Scanner operation2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String op2 = operation2.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your third number here: ");
    Scanner tnumb = new Scanner(System.in);
    double tnum = tnumb.nextDouble();

    if (op2.equals("*")) {
    double answer2 = answer * tnum;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    System.out.println(answer2);
         }
    }
}
```

So my error is here:

```
    double answer2 = answer * tnum;
```

I believe its because answer is not set until the user runs the program. The error:

```
The local variable may have not been initialised.
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is because you set variable "answer" within an if statements.
to fix the error add else statement after your if condition like

...

```
else{
answer=0.0;
}
```

or a easier solution would be to say:

```
double answer=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the local variable is not initialized and **local variables doesn't have a default values**. Assign value to the answer variable when you declare it.

```
double answer = 0.0;
```

Comment: @EvilCactus If answers helped you then upvote the. If answer solve your problem then mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Instance variables` are initialized to null or to their default primitive values, if they are primitives.

`Local variables` are undefined and are not initialized and so it is your responsibility for setting the initial value.

so change this `double answer;` to `double answer = 0;`